# How do I disable the Alert Add button in Xcode if the textField is empty?

Tags: ios, xcode

Xcode 9, iOS 11

I am using the following code to add text to an array for a TableView app in iOS:

```
@IBAction func addButtonPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    var textField = UITextField()

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Add New Task", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)

    let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Add Item", style: .default) { (action) in

      let newItem = Item(context: self.context)
      newItem.title = textField.text!
      newItem.done = false
      newItem.parentCategory = self.selectedCategory
      self.itemArray.append(newItem)

      self.saveItems()
    }

    alert.addTextField { (alertTextField) in
      alertTextField.placeholder = "Create new item"
      textField = alertTextField
    }

    alert.addAction(action)
    present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }
```

The code works fine, with one exception: it is possible to click Add Item even if the textField is blank.

How do I disable the Add Item button until text has been added to the text field?

[image]

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can accomplish this as the delegate of the `UIAlertController`'s textfield is not even calling `UITextFieldDelegate` methods which means you can't know when to set `isEnabled` property for the `UIAlertAction` , you may go custom

Comment: So do I just give up and say it can't be done? Or when you say, "you may go custom" are you saying there is a workaround?